# Plural for "будь ласка"

Tags: вживання-слів, пошанна-множина

I have found out that please will be in Ukrainian будь ласка. In terms of Russian, it looks like singular. Is there any plural form for this word?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. The existing answer confirms that there may be confusion between plural for ***будь*** (addressing to **multiple persons**) versus plural for ***ласка*** (referring to **multiple favors**). Personally, I read your question as you need the plural for ***будь***. Please [edit] the question to let us know what specifically you mean.

Comment: I agree with bytebuster. You need to clarify the question.

Comment: I just did not get if there is any plural form for please, the point of this question if there is any plural form for _please_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I get the question right, you need two types of addressing people. One is for one person you need something from, another is for multiple people or for ones you address with respectful 'you'.

If you want to address one person, whom you usually address with singular 'you' (*ти*):

> Будь ласка, допомож**и** мені.
>
> Also: Будь **твоя** ('your' singular) ласка, допоможи мені. — very rare in use but indicates the type of 'you' better.

If you want to address multiple people or one person, whom you usually address with
respectful 'you' (*ви*):

> Будь ласка, допомож**іть** мені.
>
> Будь**те** ласка**ві**, допомож**іть** мені.
>
> Also: Будь **ваша** ('your' respectful/plural) ласка, допоможіть мені. — very rare in use but indicates the type of 'you' better.

It is not a plural form of *будь ласка*, it is rather a way to use this expression for plural addressees or for those addressees you have too much respect to to say singular 'you' in Ukrainian.

Here's an interesting [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction_in_the_world%27s_languages) about T-V distinction. The Russian-Ukrainian section isn't as precise as it could be but still interesting to read if you are out of context.

Comment: What I like in these variants "будь твоя ласка"/"будь ваша ласка" is that, despite they're rarely used, they reveal origin of "будь ласка" and help to understand that singular form of _будь_ doesn't really relate to the number of addressees.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a one word; it's two words. So grammatical category of number (singular/plural) barely relates to *будь ласка*.

IIUC, *будь ласка* derives from *як буде твоя ласка* “if there will be your favor”.

*Ласка* here is a noun (“favor”). *Будь* here is an imperative-mood verb “to be” (in Ukrainian, imperative mood is sometimes used as conditional mood, e.g: “…*Май я*… хоть який невеличкий заробок…, я би з Анною міг жити в Нагуєвичах…” (I. Franko) — literally “*Have I* at least some salary, I could live with Anna in Nahuievychi” with meaning “*If I had* at least some salary, I could live with Anna in Nahuievychi”).

Thinking about grammatical category of number:

- Technically *ласка* is a singular noun. And theoretically you could put it in plural: *як будуть твої ласк**и*** “if there will be your favor**s**”, *будь ласк**и***, etc. But practically nobody says so; this phrase is too idiomatic, and you probably won't be understood is you change it in an unexpected manner; especially that the word *ласка* with meaning “favor” itself is rarely used in plural.
- The whole phrase *будь ласка* can be used both as both singular and plural noun. For example, *мені набридли твої «будь ласка»* — “I'm tired of your ‘pleases’” (can mean either “I'm tired of excessive amount of your requests”, or “I'm tired of your excessive politeness”).

Comment: See my comment under the question. Chances are, this answer is totally off the way the OP was asking about.